# How can I work with the hidden database objects in SQL Server?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, ssms

I am working with a SQL Server that, for security reasons, does not show the database names, schemas, tables, and stored procedures on the server.

I have permissions to alter and maintain the objects, just can't see them in SSMS. I'd like to know an easy way to work with the database in the ways I am accustomed to working in SSMS. Right-clicking in SSMS gives you so many options that allow productivity (especially the script to functions).

How can I 1) create a quick list of stored procedures, and 2) quickly create a script to alter a selected stored procedure?

Comment: Folks (@Mike , @FreeBird72), writing the script blind is not ideal. I would think at the very least I should be able to capture the SP code via sp_helptext  (e.g. sp_helptext 'spName' ) and copy that into an SSMS window, changing the CREATE PROCEDURE to ALTER PROCEDURE etc...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can list the objects using

```
SELECT name from sys.objects where type = 'P'
```

That should show stored procedures. However, if the objects are hidden from you you may not be able to run this.

Searching for 'U' will show you tables.

As for changing the stored procedures, you can run an `ALTER PROCEDURE ...`
But you may need to write the script blind. Or as suggested by @T K Bruin use `sp_helptext` to generate the create script will give you the basis of the alter statement.

Answer (score 1):

regarding your first question:

```
SELECT * FROM sys.procedures
SELECT * FROM sys.tables
```

see [Object Catalog Views (Transact-SQL)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189783.aspx) for more info